# Как отсылать push-уведомления

Tags: java, android, push-уведомления

Доброго времени суток. Существует необходимость отсылать push-уведомления от устройства к самому себе. Например, я запускаю службу, которая будет мониторить мое местоположение по геолокации, после чего, при нахождении определенного объекта на карте, должна отсылаться push-нотификация. Т.е. никакие дополнительные сервисы здесь никак не задействованы. Подробной информации об организации отправления push-уведомлений без использования сторонних сервисов я не нашел, к сожалению

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все ответы тут: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html?hl=ru - Push уведомления

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=ru - Сервисы android